# Did Ava a.k.a the Ghost kill agent Stoltz?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* Ghost attacked the corrupt FBI agent Stoltz when he was trying to put Hank Pym's shrunk lab in the back of his car at the woods.

After that scene, there's no mention of his name.

But the Ghost herself told Hank Pym:

> But others at SHIELD saw an opportunity in my affliction. They built me a containment suit so I can control my phasing. And trained me to be a stealth operative. They weaponized me. I stole for them, spied for them... **I killed for them**. And in exchange for my soul, they were going to cure me. They lied.

From these quotes one can conclude that she was not okay with her job and she doesn't want to kill others anymore.

So what was agent Stoltz' fate? Was he killed or just went in a coma?

[image]

Comment: The part in quote, " I killed for them" doesn't indicate about the incident with corrupt agent, It merely mentions what kind of things Ghost did when she was working for the organization.

Comment: @Vishwa I didn't connect that quote with that incident. I just said this quote shows the ghost doesn't want to kill people, but she has to.